# Как создать кнопку стрельбы в игре на движке Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Принцип игры состоит в следующем: нужно стрелять из пушки нажимая на конкретную кнопку.
Ниже я оставлю часть из C# кода, которая помогает меня стрелять из пушки, но не с помощью специальной кнопки, а нажимая на любую часть экрана. Прошу помочь преобразовать и использовать этот код с целью стрельбы с кнопки.

```
public void Update () {
         Vector3 diffarance = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
         float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(diffarance.y, diffarance.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
         transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + offset);


         if (ShotsTime <= 0) {
             if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
                 Instantiate (Arrow_1, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
                 ShotsTime = startShotsTime;    
             }
         }

         else {
             ShotsTime -= Time.deltaTime;
         }

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Создайте скрипт и повесьте его на Вашу пушку.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour {
    public void Fire()
    {
        Debug.Log ("fire"); 
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Затем создайте UI Button (ПКМ в окне иерархии `> UI > Button`)

найдите в его свойствах список слушателей и добавьте туда элемент нажав на `+`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Затем перетащите объект gun в ячейку слушателя и в выпадающем меню выберите `Gun > Fire`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

После вышеописанных действий при нажатии на кнопку будет вызван метод `Fire` у объекта `Gun`